# SQL query not returning data

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I am trying to retrieve data from a Intersystems Cached database using a `where` clause with a `timestamp`, but nothing works.

Query:

```
select * 
from dbo.iSkillsetStat 
where Timestamp >= '2014-07-29 00:00:00'
```

Error:

```
ERROR: [SQLCODE: <-4>:<A term expected, beginning with one of
the following: identifier, constant, aggregate, %ALPHAUP, %EXACT,
%MVR, %SQLSTRING, %SQLUPPER, %STRING, %UPPER, $$, :,
+, -, (, NOT, EXISTS, or FOR>]
[Location: <Prepare>]
```

If I run the query without the `timestamp` all the data is returned.

Please any suggestions!

Comment: Please remember to format your posts properly. (:

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Nope Intersystems Cache

Comment: You need to convert the dataType of the `timestamp`. what is the defined type of that field?

Answer (score 3):

as **TIMESTAMP** is a reserved word, you should enclose it in double quotes **"TIMESTAP"**

Comment: YOu are an absolute star, my query is working, never even thought about the reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

In similar cases this worked for me:

```
select * from dbo.iSkillsetStat where Timestamp >= '2014-07-29T00:00:00'
```

Note the 'T' between the date and time values.

Comment: @Liquid-Ice Could you please try one more thing? select * from dbo.iSkillsetStat where Timestamp >= '2014-07-29T00:00:00.000'

Answer (score 0):

the field `timestamp` may be a reserved keyword and shouldn't be used for columnnames (have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/141051 #728)

**HINT:**
if you field is of type `TIMESTAMP` convert the value before you compare it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.iSkillsetStat 
WHERE columnname >= TIMESTAMP('2014-07-29 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *  
from dbo.iSkillsetStat 
where Timestamp >= Convert(datetime, '2014-07-29 00:00:00')
```

Here you are missing `000` in your datetime `2014-07-29 00:00:00`.

It should be like this `2014-07-29 00:00:00:000`
instead of `2014-07-29 00:00:00`

Comment: Get the same error, tried to convert, but it is a datetime field in the db, but tried the convert, and got the same error